# Change some values of array inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

Let's say I have an array of size nx*ny:

`float *array = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*nx*ny);`

I want to change `ny` values inside a loop in each iteration using a function call

```
for(int i=0; i<nx; i++){
  change_only_ny_elements(array, ny);

}

change_only_ny_elements(float *array, int ny, int ix){
  for(int j=0; i<ny; j++){
  array[j] = ix*ny + j;
}
```

so how can i do that ? can I pass it as reference like this `change_only_ny_elements(&array[ix],ny)`

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program? And why use a C-style cast instead of no cast or a C++ cast?

Comment: @JesperJuhl why not, if it's for a fundamental type. The other point is, there's nothing about C++ in this question.

Comment: Why are you passing an array as a pointer and size when you could be using `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: How many arguments do you want the function to have?

Comment: @JesperJuhl the question is for C, not C++

Comment: @Remy It was tagged c++ when I commented.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, you are just indexing the `array` incorrectly when passing it to the function.  Try this instead:

```c
void change_only_ny_elements(float *array, int ny, int ix){
    for(int j = 0; i < ny; ++j){
        array[j] = (ix * ny) + j;
    }
}

...

float *array = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * nx * ny);
for(int i = 0; i < nx; ++i){
    change_only_ny_elements(&array[i*ny], ny, ix);
}
free(array);
```